# C# Webdriver FindsBy - Combining FindsBy Statements with similar text in ID variable in a Page Object Framework Class

Tags: c#, selenium-webdriver, pageobjects

I have adapted a Page Object Framework that was created in C# that uses the Selenium PageObjects Library to find page elements.

In my program, I have a Class with a FindsBy statement that finds a text field with the ID "ngp_total_records" (see below)

```
[FindsBy(How = How.Id, Using = "ngp_total_records")]
public IWebElement txtNGPTotalRecords { get; set; }
```

I also have a section of code that finds a similar text field but the id is different (see below)

```
[FindsBy(How = How.Id, Using = "ngp_usi_total_records")]
public IWebElement txtNGPUSITotalRecords { get; set; }
```

Question: Is there a way to combine the above FindsBy statements into one so that the "ngp_total_records" id and the "ngp_usi_total_records" id are located each time the program is executed?

Comment: I guess I'm confused as to what you are asking. Both are found when the program is executed when you use PageFactory to load the page object. They seem to represent different elements/things... why would you want to combine them?

Comment: I'd like to combine them so that I can use just one FindsBy statement to locate the (2) page objects.  That way, the program will find and click the page object with id = "ngp_total_records" or with id = "ngp_usi_total_records".  Otherwise, I will have to continue using (2) FindsBy statements for page objects that are basically the same except for the slight difference in id values.

Comment: Are both of these elements on the same page? If so, I can't imagine a reason that you would want to combine them. I guess I'd have to see the page to better understand.

Comment: Unfortunately, both of the elements are not on the same page. They are product-specific. So, if one product is selected, then that element displays. If a different product is selected, then the other element displays. The issue that I am trying to avoid is having to maintain separate code for each product that is tested on this web site.

Comment: All has become clear now... this makes sense... answer incoming.. give me a minute.

Answer (score 0):

OK. I think I understand what you are asking. If product type 1 is used, then element 1 is visible. If product type 2 is used, then element 2 is visible. Yes? Hopefully? In this case, I would do this...

You will still need both elements since the IDs are different. I would make the two "finder" elements private then have a public element that represents the one that is available for the given product. In the constructor for the page, you would check to see which element exists and assign it to the public element

```
[FindsBy(How = How.Id, Using = "ngp_total_records")]
private IWebElement txtNGPTotalRecords { get; set; }

[FindsBy(How = How.Id, Using = "ngp_usi_total_records")]
private IWebElement txtNGPUSITotalRecords { get; set; }

// no FindsBy here... this gets set in its getter
public IWebElement txtTotalRecords;
```

In the getter for `txtTotalRecords`, set it to whichever element exists. I think one issue you might have is that what happens with PageFactory when an element doesn't exist? Does it throw or just move on? I don't know because I don't use PageFactory.

---

Edit 1: updated answer based on JimEvans correction.

Comment: Yes, you're substantially right, in that the way to do this is to have two private fields, but you'd want to use a property to return the right one, not setting it in the constructor. In the property getter, you can do the correct existence/visibility checks at runtime.

Comment: @JimEvans You are right... I haven't done C# actively in a long time and my current primary language (Java) doesn't have getter/setters so I forgot about them... well you can make them in Java but they are ugly IMO.